# Mongoose .populate() does not populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I have two schema's `Role` and `User`. When I do a `Role.find()` I want to populate the `users` with the users that have that specific role.

```js
let roleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ...,
  users: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

const Role = mongoose.model('Role', roleSchema);
```

```js
let userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ...,
  role: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Role'
  },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I get the `Role` with the following code:

```js
Role.findById(req.params.roleId)
  .populate('users')
  .then(role => {
    res.send(role);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.send(err)
});
```

It returns the following:

```
{  
   "users": [  

   ],
   "_id":"5c78006df35ca926534ad865",
   "name":"Role",
   "createdAt":"2019-02-28T15:38:21.741Z",
   "updatedAt":"2019-02-28T15:38:21.741Z",
   "__v":0
}
```

`User.find().populate('role')` works just fine, but `Role.find().populate('users')` doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong or don't I need `.populate()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I think I had to use `aggregate().lookup()` for that all along... since there weren't any ids in `Role.users`...

```js
Role.aggregate()
  .lookup({
    from: 'users',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'role',
    as: 'users'
  }).then( role => {
    res.send(role);
  });
```

This gave me the response I wanted.